# MeteorJS can not update count on document

Tags: methods, meteor, mongodb-query

This is my function and it does not update the count on the NumStat collection document.

```
Meteor.methods({
addDocument: function(array){
    object = {
        numbers : array,
        date : new Date()
    }
    NumArray.insert(object);

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        NumStat.update({num : array[i]},{$inc : {count : 1}});
        console.log(NumStat.findOne({num : array[i]})); // this throws undefined
    }
}
});
```

if I do something like:
    NumStat.update({num : 2},{$inc : {count : 1}});
It works perfectly but not something like the example that I motioned !? What is wrong with this method and how can I come to the result that I want ? Increasing the count on the NumStat documents finding the document by array[item]

Solution : 
It was my bad because the value on the array was a string and the num value on the database was an int. The solution was using parseInt(array[i]). A better solution will be using findAndModify as @Dewfy mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know JavaScript implementation for Mongo at all, but:

1. `update` for other dialect (Java or C#) doesn't create record but update existing one, so review usage of `save`
2. In Mongo there is a conception of '[write concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/)' - that may delay real writing. Ensure that you deal with Acknowledged.

p.s. Instead of loop use `findAndModify` with specifying array of IDs to modify - then you could avoid loop and place modification logic to server side

Comment: Thank you very much for the fundAndMdofiy function i'm going to use it. As for the array[i] it was my bad the item of the array was string and the num value on the database was a int